# SpriteKit runaction done event callng a method

Tags: sprite-kit

Using SpriteKit cocos2d, i would like to call an method when the done delegate is executed...

```
       SKAction *actionMoveDone = [SKAction removeFromParent];
    [self.neko runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[actionMove, actionMoveDone]]];
```

Currently it appears as the actionMoveDone delegate (i think) is called, the SKAction is performed, removing it from the parent...   but what I would like to do is call another method so i can update my variables then execute the removeFromParent.

But I am unsure of how to actually call a method as the end of sequence delegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `SKAction` can have a `runBlock` which you can use to execute code. e.g.

```
SKAction *yourAction =   [SKAction runBlock:^{
        //your code to update variables
}];
```

then add it into the sequence in the relevant location:

```
[self.neko runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[actionMove,yourAction, actionMoveDone]]];
```